# Car Inductive Charger Module?

Tags: automotive, charger, inductive

I will try to design an inductive charger which will run by using cigar lighter of the car. Does anybody have any suggestions on my project? Taking the power from cigar lighter is easy but how should I choose my circuit components for best ergonomy & efficiency?

Comment: Duplicate? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2178/inductive-charging

Comment: nope, I opened it after getting down votes refer to my question there...!

Answer (score 2):

The guys over at seeedstudio sell a [ready-made inductive transmitter/receiver pair](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/wireless-power-supply-p-701.html?cPath=155), designed specifically for charging batteries. Input voltage is 12V, so it would be an excellent fit for automotive applications. I have no experience with it, but at $\$$9.50 it might be worth a shot.

Both the transmitter and the receiver should fit in a flat 50x60mm housing, so i suggest you design your product on a similar footprint. It is hard to comment on ergonomics without knowing at least the shape of what you are planning to charge, the approximate interior arrangement of the vehicle and whether it's intended to be operated by the driver or the passengers.

Comment: I plan to integrate the charging pad into the glove box or on central console,  I did not decided yet.But the most important case for me is the efficiency & quality of the components, because there are lots of regulations on automotive industry.There should not be any interferences by other signals (key system,radio system etc...)

Comment: It's a common misconception that cars provide a 12V power supply. While the Lead-Acid battery is in fact a 12V battery, there are a LOT of different states in a cars power supply network which will kill any electronic in an instant unless it is correctly protected. On cold start the power might drop down to 5V. When the motor is running and the battery is charging you'll have 14-15 Volts. There is a lot of noise on the power lines, fast transients up to 100 or 200 Volts need to be handled and the infamous load dump, which can be up to 100V for half a second or so.